# How to prove one point compactification in $T_2$ space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove this theorem which states  :   Let $(Y,$$\sigma$$)$ be a compact $T_2$ space and $y$$\in$$Y$.Let $X=Y-${$y$}. Then$ Y$ is the one point compactification of $X$.

My Try________________

$Y$ is $T_2$. {$y$} is closed  in $T_2$ as $T_2$ space implies $T_1$ also and hence $Y-${$y$} $\in$ $\sigma$.Let $U$$\in$$\sigma$ such that $y$ $\notin$$U$ $\implies$$U$$\subset$$X$

Now we define the subspae topology $(X,$$\tau$$)$ as $X$$\cap$$U$ $\in$ $\tau$,for all $U$ $\subset$ $X$

Thus clearly $y$ $\notin$$U$$\implies$$U=X$$\cap$$U$$\in$$\tau$

If $y$$\in$ $U$ $\in$ $\sigma$

Then $Y-U$ is closed in $(Y,$$\tau$$)$

$\implies$ $Y-U$$\cup$$\{$ $p$ $\}$ is closed in $Y$, union of two closed sets
$\implies$ $Y-$[$U$ $\cap${$p$}$^c$ $]$ is closed in $Y$

$\implies$ $U$ $\cap${$p$}$^c$ is open in $Y$

$\implies$ $U$$\cap${$p$}$^c$ is open in $(X$,$\tau$)
$\implies$
 $X$$\cap$[$U$$\cap$ {$p$}$^c$] $^c$ is closed in $X$

$\implies$X$\cap$$U$$^c$(=$Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$) is closed in $X$

Now I have to show $Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$ is compact in $X$.

As $Y$ is given compact $Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$ is ccompact in $Y$.

Let $Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$ has a collection of open cover $(X$$\cap$$U$$_A$) due to subspace topology,

Now as $X$ is oopen in$Y$ topology all those open set of above collection {$A$} are open in $Y$.Now we have a open cover of $Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$ in $Y$.Since every closed subset of compact space is also compact $Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$ is compact in Y and hence has a finite subcollection of {$A$}to cover it.

This finite subcolection are all in ($X$,$\tau$) also. Thus $Y$$\cap$$U$$^c$ is compact in $X$ and closed in $X$.

and hence $Y$ is compactification of $X$ but i used the property of $T_1$ space to assume {$y$} as closed,infact my procedure tells that the above theorem is valid even in $T_1$ space But my teacher has given me example where the above one compactness does not occur in $T_1$ space.So surely there is something which I have missed in above procedure,Please help me to find out my misstake.I will be happy if someone give me a hint to prove it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's not a problem that you used the T_1 property in your proof. Just because the theorem fails for a T_1 space does not mean it fails for all of them. However there is a problem: the theorem does not hold for all T_2 spaces either. A simple example: any finite Y.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what  worries you about your proof. You're quite right that you haven't used anything stronger than the T_1 property and so there's something wrong.  To be frank, I can't make sense of your proof.  To show Y is a one-point compactification of X you need to show X is dense in Y. (We already know it is compact and has one more point than X.) You need an extra condition on X. I would suggest that you specify X is not compact. Now see if you can prove Y is the closure of X, using what you know about compact subspaces of T_2 spaces.

Comment: What is your definition of "the one point compactification of $X$"?

Comment: If  $y$ is an isolated point of $Y$ then $X$ is already compact. If  $y$ is not an isolated point of $Y$ then $ id_X:X\to Y$ is a dense homeomorphic embedding of $X$ into $Y.$

Comment: @DavidHartley Sorry, I had to show $Y-U$ is compact also if $p\in$ $U$ which I have done now.I have tried to prove $Y$ as the compactification of $X$  from the  definition of one point compactification that says if $Y$=$X$$\cup$${p}$ and the topology on $Y$ ={$U$:$U$ is open in $X$ or $Y-A$ is closed and compact in $X$ if $p$$\in$$U$}. I can't understand how did you say  the finite set $Y$ in $T_2$ space  does not  satisfy the result.Every finite set is compact in any topology and I think it's very trivial case the motivation of compactification us to extend a noncompact space to compact space

Comment: @DavidHartley let me try as you suggested.probably you are saying an equivalent defininition of one point compactness.Isn't it?

Comment: But still,I haven't used $T_2$ space property!

Comment: definition of one point compactification  says if $Y$=$X$$\cup${$p$} and the topology on $Y$ ={$U$:$U$ is open in $X$ or $Y−A$ is closed and compact in $X$} ,$Y$ is compact

Comment: By definition a one-point compactification of X is a compactification with just one extra point. Under certain conditions you can construct one by adding a distinct point p and forming the space Y as you describe (you need the conditions to ensure that the family of subsets you give does form a topology). But you're coming from a different direction. You start with compact Y so, as long as y is not isolated, it must be a compactification of X. ....

Comment: ... So it seems what you should be proving is that if you constructed the one-point compactification in the standard way - using y as your point - you would get the same Y.  I.e. the same topology on Y. You need to sure open sets in one topology are open in the other *and vice-versa*.

Comment: (Sorry, that posted before I finished - or corrected the typos)) ...  For one of these directions you will have to show that certain compact sets are closed, that's where you need the T_2 property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76847/discussion-between-subhajit-saha-and-david-hartley).